# Kaa code flow - server to endpoint

Tags: kaa

I tried debugging the kaa source code and I needed help to understand the correct flow.

My understanding:
As soon as endpoint application starts it sends KAAConnect message to the server and then server does endpoint profiling and registration.

My question:
if we send configuration, how it reaches to the endpoint, What I observe endpoint also sends KAASYNC message to the server.

Is it some kind of polling it is doing?

atleast the basic flow how server interacts with endpoint in case of notification or configuration?

Please clarify my doubts!

Answer (score 0):

To configure an endpoint, the Kaa Configuration subsystem sends structured data from Kaa server to that endpoint. See [Configuration management](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Programming-guide/Key-platform-features/Configuration-management/)
documentation for details. For details about notification feature look at the 
[Notifications](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Programming-guide/Key-platform-features/Notifications/) documentation page.